# Boost para audio mp3 con javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Estoy intentando tocar este sonido https://www.elongsound.com/images/mp3/timbre_de_bicicleta_2.mp3 5 veces más alto, pero no puedo:

```js
document.getElementById("myaudio").volume = 5;
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("myaudio").play();},1);
setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("myaudio").pause();document.getElementById("myaudio").currentTime = 0;},2000);
```

```html
<audio id="myaudio">
<source src="https://www.elongsound.com/images/mp3/timbre_de_bicicleta_2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>
```

No me deja reproducir el audio porque el *document.getElementById("myaudio").volume = **5**;*
solo puede ser como máximo 1, como podría subir el volumen.
Acepto usar jQuery.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: No se puede subir el volumen por encima del 100%, que es representado por 1

Comment: Como dice @pablo-lozano no es posible asignar un valor de volumen por encima de 1. Lo que sí podrías hacer es utilizar la interfaz AudioContext para crear un nuevo MediaElementAudioSourceNode y aumentarle el volumen (o añadirle efectos). Échale un vistazo a esta respuesta de SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794356/html5-volume-increase-past-100?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa